# How to make sure HTTP Request completed then proceed to next request using JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, test-design, test-strategy

Recently I'm new to `JMeter`, I have `9 HTTP requests` and I want to make sure all the threads must run accordingly in order to complete the whole task in my project. Moreover, I do not think, that adding a synchronizing timer is the best answer to suit in my scenario. Right now I have 100 threads, ramp-up period is 1 second, forever loop until 10 mins. The problem occurs like this:

```
HTTP request 1
HTTP request 2
HTTP request 3
HTTP request 5 <--- Must complete HTTP request 4 first. otherwise got problems in my system.
HTTP request 4 
HTTP request 6
HTTP request 7
HTTP request 8
HTTP request 9
```

`HTTP request` 4 might take sometimes, because that step is actually registration part.

What I want to achieve
`HTTP request 1` - 9 accordingly. So that my system will register the user correctly.

I hope, that my explanation can give you more clearer image.

Answer (score 3):

JMeter runs [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)) to wit given the following [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan):

[image]

**Each JMeter thread** will **always** execute `Request 1` first and then `Request 2`

When you have > 1 thread (virtual user) you may see that request order is broken, however if you add [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as the request prefix/postfix you will see that actually each thread executes samplers in the order they appear in the Test Plan:

[image]

If you experience issues with number of threads > 1 it indicates a problem with your test plan, i.e. you forgot to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) or the clash is due to missing or improperly working [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) (handling of dynamic parameters)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I am still having the same issue where the request 5 happen before request 4. Do you think that the network and my backend system to handle the request might delay the request? So if request 4 is processing while jmeter is sending request 5 as well. Somehow request 5 has done whereas request 4 still processing. Do you think something like this will happen? If yes, how can i solve it without using synchronizing timer.

Comment: Does jmeter wait for the proper request in each iteration while other iterations running smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Could you rename your requests by adding "Thread ${__threadNum}" prefix to your "Request 1", "Request 2", etc so they will look like etc into "Thread ${__threadNum} Request 1", "Thread ${__threadNum} Request 2", etc.

After that, run test and show the sequence of requests please.